# How can i store mysql databases in linux using shell scripting

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

How can i store mysql databases in linux using shell scripting

script:

```
mysql -uusername -hhostname -ppassword -e "show databases"
```

Comment: I want to store all database names in an array so tha I can call them and perform a query on all of them one by one using for loop

Comment: @adarshhota `shell_exec` is PHP function, this question is about shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/96132

```
mysql> use mysql
Database changed
mysql> tee /tmp/mysqltee
Logging to file '/tmp/mysqltee'
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_mysql |
+-----------------+
| columns_priv    |
| db              |
| host            |
| tables_priv     |
| user            |
+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> notee
Outfile disabled.
mysql>
```

If the file exist, the output will be appended to the existing file (/tmp/mysqltee).

As you can see, the output is also displayed on the screen. This may not be
what you want, especially if the output is big... You could use

```
 mysql -e "select table_name from user_tables" database > output.txt
```

or

```
 mysql database < script.sql > output.txt
```

from the os command line. (You may also need to use -u, -p and/or -h, use
the same as when you do a 'normal' start of the mysql client.)

Comment: The OP wants to do this from a shell script without going into mysql itself

Answer (score 0):

it may help you

```
 #!/bin/bash
 results=($(mysql --user root -pwelcome -Bse "show databases;"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will retrieve all database names into a variable called dbnames. After that, it iterates will just echo a string with each name individually

```
#!/bin/bash
dbnames=`mysql --user=user --password=password -se "show databases;"`

for x in $dbnames;
do
    echo "There is a database called $x"
done;
```

Comment: what command should I use if I want to show value of only on database name, suppose second database.

Comment: Introduce requiredRow and count variables to the script. Increment count on each iteration through the loop and compare it to the requiredRow value. Use `requiredRow=$((requiredRow+1))` to perform the increment.